# Using NPM in application with perl backend breaks functionality

Tags: perl, npm

I inherited a legacy application that uses jQuery on the frontend, and in a horrible lapse of judgement I ran

```
npm install underscore
```

And then immediately punched myself, because the backend of this application is written in perl! So now, when I attempt to access the site I get the following error:

```
Error: No such CGI app - /var/www/html/login.pl may not exist or is not executable by this process.
```

/var/ww/html/login.pl does in fact exist. It starts off like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use utf8;
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw /param/;
use Digest::PBKDF2;
use CGI::Cookie;
use MongoDB;
use Data::Dumper;
use UUID::Generator::PurePerl;
```

Then proceeds to do some login stuff. This worked fine when the application actually ran. Other answers suggest npm overwrites index.html, but this still exists and still redirects to the login.pl script.

I know this is not a good question by any reasonable standards but I'm getting desperate.

Comment: The error is "/var/www/html/login.pl may not exist or is not executable by this process". You say "/var/ww/html/login.pl does in fact exist." So, is it executable?

Comment: The permissions are a+rwx. So yes, I've double checked that it both exists and is executable.

Comment: `chmod a+rwx` is terrible practise in general but especially bad for a web app. `chmod 755` is much safer.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to chmod 755.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently NPM changes permissions. I ended up restoring functionality by running the following:

```
find /html -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

And then:

```
find /html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

This allows the perl interpreter to execute all files in the html directory.